# laravel elasticseach and custom field mapping

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

I'm using laravel 4.1 (quite old project) and Elasticquent plugin for elasticsearch. I have a problem with custom field mapping. I'm using elasticsearch for orders in admin panel. Here is the issue:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Modules\Order\Models;

use Elasticquent\ElasticquentTrait;
class Order extends \Eloquent
{
  use ElasticquentTrait;

    /**
     * Table name
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'order';

    protected $mappingProperties = array(
        'original_id' => [
          'type' => 'string',
        ],
        'client_id' => [
          'type' => 'string',
        ],
        'created' => [
          'type' => 'datetime'
        ],
        'login' => [
          'type' => 'string',
        ],
    );


    public function getIndexDocumentData()
    {
        $login = $this->client_id ? $this->client->where('id','=',$this->client_id)->get(['login'])[0]->login : null;
        return array(
            'id' => $this->id,
            'original_id'        => $this->original_id,
            'client_id'      => (int)$this->client_id,
            'created'      => $this->created,
            'login' => $login ? $login : 'niezarejestrowany',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Fields that can by field
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = array('original_id', 'client_id', 'created', 'login');

    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Epro\Modules\Order\Models\Client');
    }
}
```

after I've add everthing to index:

```
Order::addAllToIndex();
```

I'm getting all orders with searchByQuery method:

```
$orders = Order::searchByQuery(['match_all' => []], null, null, 10, null, ['created'=>'asc']);
```

and try to order everything with created field. But there is a problem - all my fields is string type. Here is the var_dump of $orders

```
object(Elasticquent\ElasticquentResultCollection)[1846]
protected 'took' => int 20
protected 'timed_out' => boolean false
protected 'shards' => 
  array (size=3)
    'total' => int 5
    'successful' => int 5
    'failed' => int 0
protected 'hits' => 
  array (size=3)
    'total' => int 221
    'max_score' => null
    'hits' => 
      array (size=10)
        0 => 
          array (size=6)
            '_index' => string 'tim' (length=3)
            '_type' => string 'order' (length=5)
            '_id' => string '3011' (length=4)
            '_score' => null
            '_source' => 
              array (size=10)
                'id' => string '3011' (length=4)
                'original_id' => string '665885' (length=9)
                'shipment_id' => null
                'dealdate' => string '2016-07-25 11:56:00' (length=19)
                'login' => string 'gldka_76' (length=9)
                'account' => string 'carpets' (length=16)
                'document_status' => string '0' (length=1)
                'is_special' => null
                'payu_status' => string 'finished' (length=11)
                'allegro_payment' => string 'tt' (length=2)
            'sort' => 
              array (size=1)
                0 => string '00' (length=2)
        1 => 
          array (size=6)
            '_index' => string 'tim' (length=3)
            '_type' => string 'order' (length=5)
            '_id' => string '3092' (length=4)
            '_score' => null
            '_source' => 
              array (size=10)
                'id' => string '3092' (length=4)
                'original_id' => string '622334271' (length=9)
                'shipment_id' => null
                'dealdate' => string '2016-07-27 13:00:44' (length=19)
                'login' => string 'Klfa01' (length=9)
                'account' => string 'account2' (length=13)
                'document_status' => string '0' (length=1)
                'is_special' => null
                'payu_status' => string '' (length=0)
                'allegro_payment' => string 'odp' (length=21)
            'sort' => 
              array (size=1)
                0 => string '00' (length=2)
```

and here is an example how orders is sorting with order by created asc:

2016-07-25 11:56
2016-07-27 13:00
2016-07-25 00:39
2016-07-22 22:00
2016-07-28 00:16
2016-07-28 13:35

I think that this wrong ordering is because of this string type in _source in above var_dump field but really don't know how to change this - is it really possible to order by datetime field ?

Comment: I think I found solution. This date format "Y-m-d H:i:s" is incorrect. Correct one is "Y/m/d H:i:s" so in getIndexDocumentData I need to pass correct date format :)